# c# asp.net mvc - calling script function from html.actionlink with a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, onclick

I have the following code -

```
@model MyFirstProject.Models.Product

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AtC(prodid) {
        var url = "/Shopping/AddToCart/";
        $.post(url, { pID: prodid });
    }
</script>

<table style="background-color:gray; padding:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3 align="center">@Model.Title</h3>
            <p align="center" style="color:white">@Model.UploadDate.Day.@Model.UploadDate.Month.@Model.UploadDate.Year</p>
            <p align="center">@Model.ShortDescription</p>
        </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "Index", "Shopping", null, new {onclick = "AtC()", @style="color: White;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Show product details", "ProductDetails", new {pID = Model.ProductID}, new { @style = "color: White;" })</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to send to the AtC function an int: Model.ProductID. I've tried several methods to fix it but nothing works. Please help, because I don't know what to do.

**Update**
Thanks pλul' this was exactly what I needed!
My problem was solved!

Comment: Try to write javascript:AtC(); instead "Index", "Shopping". Let me edit this quickly: What is happening right now is you are going to a link and not activating a javascript function (you are doing both) and this page move is disturbing your function running

Comment: This would work: new {onclick = "AtC(" + @Model.ProductID + ")"
Although there's not really any point using an ActionLink for this as you're not doing anything with the ActionLink other than adding an onclick handler

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "Index", "Shopping", null, 
                     new { onclick = "AtC("+Model.ProductID+")", @style = "color: red;" })
```

I personally prefer to do unobtrusive javascript so that my markup will not have any direct calls to the javascript method. To do this, we will  add an Id to the link.

Since you are posting to the Shopping/AddToCart method, you can use those 2 when you build your action link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Shopping", new {@id=Model.ProductID},
                                          new { @id="addToCart", style = "color: green;" })
```

Now in javascript listen to the click event of the anchor tag with id "addToCart", and do your ajax post

```
$(function(){

   $("a#addToCart").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(response){
          console.log(response);
      });    
   });

});
```

If you want to send additional information, you can keep those as html5 data attributes in your link and use that as needed

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "Shopping", new { @id = Model.ProductID},
                  new { @id = "addToCart",data_size="large", style = "color: green;" })
```

And in your javascript you can read these additional information

```
$("a#addToCart").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var d = { Size : $(this).data("size");
    $.post($(this).attr("href"),d,function(response){
          console.log(response);
    });    
});
```